# Why i get "Infinite expression 1/0.^5 encountered" in summation?

Tags: summation

this is my code 
the file 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1foOFbyAnn4buPgHq_LvF5eGjZYm4SEM-

```
a = Import["C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\stars\\filecoor.txt", "Table"];
p = 2; 
k02 = 1/4; 
\[Sigma] = 0.6; 
R2 = 0.917; 
B02 = (1/4)*(1 - \[Sigma])*R2*
   Sum[(-a[[i,5]])*Sqrt[a[[i,2]]^2 + Sum[(a[[i,n]] - a[[1,3]])^2, {n, 3, 4}]]*
     Sqrt[a[[i,2]]^2 + Sum[((a[[i,n]] - a[[1,3]])^2)^(-(2*p + 1)), {n, 3, 4}]], 
    {i, 1, Length[a]}]
```

why i get this erreur

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^5 encountered.
>   Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subtract a number from itself, you get 0. When you raise 0 to a negative power, you're performing an operation that is illegal in mathematics. This is essentially what you've programmed:

```
0^(-5)
```

Here's the subset of your code where it happens:

```
Sum[((a[[i, n]] - a[[1, 3]])^2)^(-(2*p + 1)), {n, 3, 4}] /. i -> 1
```

or more specifically

```
((-2.715253` + 2.715253`)^2)^(-(2*p + 1)) (* where p=2 *)
```

Looking closely at this portion of your code specifically may give some hints as to what you need to do to resolve the issue for yourself:

```
Table[Sum[((a[[i, n]] - a[[1, 3]])^2)^(-(2*p + 1)), {n, 3, 4}], {i, 1,
    1074}]
```